# Android TextViews not Updating With New Text in onCreate Method of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I am adding TextViews to a simple application, running some code to determine what text should show in each one, then displaying it based on what a user previously entered in a bundle.

The problem is no text is showing up at all!

I am running code in the onCreate method that determines what text should show based on passed in values from a previous activity in a bundle. The values seem to pass in without an error and the other Textviews in the activity reflect the changes, but not the income, expenses or incomeExpenses TextView.

Here is my code:

```
    package androidbro.costoflivingcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.Console;


public class FinalGrade extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Grade and message strings
    public String myGrade;
    public String finalMessage;

    //Doubles for calculated values
    public double rentMortgage;
    public double utilities;
    public double insurance;
    public double phoneInternet;
    public double food;
    public double carPayment;
    public double misc;
    public double myIncome;
    public double totalExpenses;
    public double expensesToIncome;


    //Calculate grade based on expenses to income ratio
    public String getGrade(double expensesToIncome) {
        String grade = "A";

        if (expensesToIncome<=0.3) {
            grade = "A";
        } else if (expensesToIncome<=0.4){
            grade = "B";
        } else if (expensesToIncome<=0.6) {
            grade = "C";
        } else if (expensesToIncome<=0.8) {
            grade = "D";
        } else {
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;
    }
    //Determine final message
    public String getFinalMessage(String grade){
        String finalMessage;
        if (grade == "A"){
            finalMessage = "You are living well within your means! You could probably afford to spend more. Either way, great work!";
        } else if(grade == "B"){
            finalMessage = "You are doing great! Your expenses are well below your income. There are a few areas to improve, but good work!";
        } else if(grade == "C") {
            finalMessage = "Not too bad, but not great either. You might be in trouble if you lost your income. Try to improve a little!";
        } else if(grade == "D") {
            finalMessage = "Uh oh! You are spending well over half the money you earn! Consider saving and investing more or it could be trouble.";
        } else {
            finalMessage = "Oh no! You are spending almost all your income! Save a little and live within your means or else you'll be broke!";
        }
        return finalMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_grade);
        //Income, expenses and bundles
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
         rentMortgage = b.getDouble("rentmortgage");
         utilities = b.getDouble("utilities");
         insurance = b.getDouble("insurance");
         phoneInternet = b.getDouble("car");
         food = b.getDouble("phone");
         carPayment = b.getDouble("food");
         misc = b.getDouble("misc");
         myIncome = b.getDouble("myincome");
         totalExpenses = rentMortgage+utilities+insurance+phoneInternet+food+carPayment+misc;
         expensesToIncome = totalExpenses/myIncome;
        //Set final message and grade values
         myGrade = getGrade(expensesToIncome);
         finalMessage = getFinalMessage(myGrade);
        //TextViews for setting values
        TextView gradeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gradeView);
        TextView messageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageView);
        TextView income = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.income);
        TextView expenses = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expenses);
        TextView incomeExpenses = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incomeExpenses);
        //Display final grade and message
        gradeView.setText(myGrade);
        messageView.setText(finalMessage);
        income.setText(Double.toString(myIncome));
        expenses.setText(Double.toString(totalExpenses));
        incomeExpenses.setText(Double.toString(expensesToIncome));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_final_grade, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }







    //Display expenses, income and expenses to income percentage on final grade
}
```

And here is my XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="ericleeconklin.costoflivingcalculator.FinalGrade">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Grade:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/gradeView"
        android:textSize="85dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You are living well within your means! You could probably afford to spend more. Either way, great work!"
        android:id="@+id/messageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gradeView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Monthly Income:"
        android:id="@+id/yourIncome"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/income"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ff77ff75"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yourIncome"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="sdsdfsd"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="23dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Expenses:"
        android:id="@+id/yourExpenses"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/income"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yourIncome"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/yourIncome"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/incomeExpenses"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ff77ff75"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/expenses"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ff77ff75"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yourExpenses"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/incomeExpenses"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/incomeExpenses"
        android:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Expenses/Income"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yourExpenses"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/incomeExpenses"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/incomeExpenses"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Here are some tips:"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:paddingTop="350dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it or try getting values in logcat/toast

Comment: just a side note use AppCompatActivity from the support library ActionBarActivity is now deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of this**:

```
income.setText(Double.toString(myIncome));
expenses.setText(Double.toString(totalExpenses));
incomeExpenses.setText(Double.toString(expensesToIncome));
```

**Do this**:

```
income.setText(String.valueOf(myIncome);
expenses.setText(String.valueOf(totalExpenses));
incomeExpenses.setText(String.valueOf(expensesToIncome));
```

I have updated my answer

**For passing double value between Activity**:

```
Intent inent = new Intent(thisActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("myincome", myIncome);  // myIncome is your double value here
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**To get value in next Activity**:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
double myIncome = b.getDouble("myincome");
```

Check your procedure of passing double value, I have mentioned it above

**Edited XML Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_BigHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your Grade:"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Grade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_BigHeading"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Grade"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="You are living well within your means! You could probably afford to spend more. Either way, great work!"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yourIncome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Monthly Income:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/incomeValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yourIncome"
            android:background="#ff77ff75"
            android:text="1000 $"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yourExpenses"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yourIncome"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Expenses:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expenseValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/incomeValue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yourExpenses"
            android:background="#ff77ff75"
            android:text="1000 $"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Expenses_Income"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yourExpenses"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Expenses/Income:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Expenses_Income_Value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/expenseValue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Expenses_Income"
            android:background="#ff77ff75"
            android:text="1000 $"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Expenses_Income"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Here are some tips:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This will solve your issue now, and use all my recommendations e.g: `income.setText(String.valueOf(myIncome);` 
for setting the textview values

Comment: Thanks, I'll post back with a result and vote this question best if it works.

Comment: Says cannot resolve method ValueOf(double). Any ideas?

Comment: NVM. It's valueOf not ValueOf. Let me run the program and see what it does.

Comment: I tried it. The valueOf is not attaching anything to the TextViews at all, it is simply doing the same thing it was before, which is nothing.

Comment: can you debug the program ? Are the values there ? Are they not empty ? Because this must do

Comment: Also, the TextViews won't even display default data in the XML file.

Comment: Did you debug the values ?

Comment: I did. The values are coming up normal. The TextViews are not showing up a value no matter what. Do you see any errors in my XML that might cause this?

Comment: You have messed with the xml, I must charge you to do the fixing :) will be back with the fix

Comment: Hope it will work now for you check & accept the answer

Comment: Okay cool, I will try this when I get home. At work right now, no Android Studio!

Comment: WOW! Worked perfectly. You mind telling me what you fixed?

Comment: you messed between padding & margin, I have fixed them

Comment: I can explain. lets take two textviews, margin is used for space between two textviews, while padding is used for space inside textview

Comment: Duh. I knew that but I missed it on this app.

Comment: Cheers mate. Thanks for the help.